# http transfer file from server to server

Tags: php, html, file-upload

with html forms we can upload a file from a client to a server with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, input `type="file"` and so on.

Is there a way to have a file already ON the server and transfer it to another server the same way?

Thanks for hints.

// WoW! This is the fastest question answering page i have ever seen!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the browser is uploading a file to the server, it sends an HTTP POST request, that contains the file's content.

You'll have to replicate that.

With PHP, the simplest *(or, at least, most used)* solution is probably to work with [**`curl`**][1].

If you take a look at the list of options you can set with [**`curl_setopt`**](https://www.php.net/curl_setopt), you'll see this one : **`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`** *(quoting)* :

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST"
> operation. 
> **To post a file,
> prepend a filename with @ and use the
> full path**. 
> This can either be
> passed as a urlencoded string like
> 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an
> array with the field name as key and
> field data as value. 
> If value is
> an array, the Content-Type header will
> be set to multipart/form-data.

Not tested,but I suppose that something like this should do the trick -- or at least
help you get started :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/your-destination-script.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'file' => '@/..../file.jpg',
         // you'll have to change the name, here, I suppose
         // some other fields ?
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Basically, you :

- are using curl
- have to set the destination URL
- indicate you want `curl_exec` to return the result, and not output it
- are using `POST`, and not `GET`
- are posting some data, including a file -- note the `@` before the file's path.

Comment: +1, I didn't realize it was as simple as using the `@` symbol with PHP :-)

Comment: last set option should be "curl_setopt"

Comment: Hi @Pascal MARTIN I use the same curl call, but in destination script I am getting data in `$_POST` not in `$_FILES`. Can you please help why?

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple PHP script I frequently use for while moving big files from server to servers.

```
set_time_limit(0); //Unlimited max execution time

$path = 'newfile.zip';
$url = 'http://example.com/oldfile.zip';
$newfname = $path;
echo 'Starting Download!<br>';
$file = fopen ($url, "rb");
if($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
    if($newf)
        while(!feof($file)) {
            fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            echo '1 MB File Chunk Written!<br>';
        }
}
if($file) {
    fclose($file);
}
if($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
}
echo 'Finished!';
```

Comment: This code reads file not sends file. Big difference

Answer (score 3):

you can do it in the same way. Just this time your server who received the file first is the client and the second server is your server. 
Try using these:

For the webpage on the second server:

```
  <form>
         <input type="text" name="var1" />
         <input type="text" name="var2" />
         <input type="file" name="inputname" />
         <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

And as a script to send the file on the first server:

```
<?php
function PostToHost($host, $port, $path, $postdata, $filedata) {
     $data = "";
     $boundary = "---------------------".substr(md5(rand(0,32000)),0,10);
     $fp = fsockopen($host, $port);

     fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.0\n");
     fputs($fp, "Host: $host\n");
     fputs($fp, "Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$boundary."\n");

     // Ab dieser Stelle sammeln wir erstmal alle Daten in einem String
     // Sammeln der POST Daten
     foreach($postdata as $key => $val){
         $data .= "--$boundary\n";
         $data .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"".$key."\"\n\n".$val."\n";
     }
     $data .= "--$boundary\n";

     // Sammeln der FILE Daten
     $data .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$filedata[0]}\"; filename=\"{$filedata[1]}\"\n";
     $data .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n";
     $data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";
     $data .= $filedata[2]."\n";
     $data .= "--$boundary--\n";

     // Senden aller Informationen
     fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($data)."\n\n");
     fputs($fp, $data);

     // Auslesen der Antwort
     while(!feof($fp)) {
         $res .= fread($fp, 1);
     }
     fclose($fp);

     return $res;
}

$postdata = array('var1'=>'test', 'var2'=>'test');
$data = file_get_contents('Signatur.jpg');
$filedata = array('inputname', 'filename.jpg', $data);

echo PostToHost ("localhost", 80, "/test3.php", $postdata, $filedata);
?>
```

Both scripts are take from here: http://www.coder-wiki.de/HowTos/PHP-POST-Request-Datei

Comment: Using PHP 7.1, I get Error 400: Bad request

Answer (score 0):

Ex. if you have a file called mypicture.gif on server A and want to send it to server B, you can use CURL.

1. Server A reads the content as a String.
2. Post the string with CURL to Server B
3. Server B fetches the String and stores it as a file called mypictyre-copy.gif

See `http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php`

Some sample PHP code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, _VIRUS_SCAN_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // same as <input type="file" name="file_box">
    $post = array(
        "file_box"=>"@/path/to/myfile.jpg",
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to transfer file one server into another server.**

First, need to enable **ssh2 php extension** and use the following code

```
$strServer = '*.*.*.*';
$strServerPort = '*';
$strServerUsername = '*****';
$strServerPassword = '****';

**//connect to server**
$resConnection = ssh2_connect($strServer, $strServerPort);
         if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword))
         {
            //Initialize SFTP subsystem            
         $resSFTP = ssh2_sftp($resConnection);             
         $resFile = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$resSFTP}/FilePath/".$filename, 'w');
         $srcFile = fopen($path.$filename, 'r');
         $writtenBytes = stream_copy_to_stream($srcFile, $resFile);
         fclose($resFile);
         fclose($srcFile);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

***It is Very easy.This is very easy & simple code***

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
/*the following 2 lines are not mandatory but we keep it to 
avoid risk of exceeding default execution time and mamory*/
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

/*url of zipped file at old server*/
$file = 'http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Xp0DOC6nW4E/maxresdefault.jpg';

/*what should it name at new server*/
$dest = 'files.jpg';

/*get file contents and create same file here at new server*/
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$handle = fopen($dest,"wb");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
echo 'Copied Successfully.';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

---

Type your Url in this variable -    `$file ="http://file-url"`

Type your file save as in hosting sever-    `$dest = 'files.jpg';`