# PHP - Push Data in Realtime in CSV Format

Tags: php

Is there a way to push data in real time to an external server in CSV format without getting request time out. We are working in custom php.

Cheers,

Hasan

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use javascript to control websocket, get the additional content, append to the local CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fputscv` to create an csv file, and `curl` to send the data to an external server using HTTP POST. There is a lot of information about the topic around, e.g:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php

[http transfer file from server to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578128/http-transfer-file-from-server-to-server)